# arm-linux-androideabi stl compile error

Tags: c++, linux, stl, android-ndk, google-breakpad

I'm currently trying to build the android version of google breakpad on a linux machine.  But it seems I'm having some issues getting the stl to be properly referenced.

I get past the configure step running ..

> ./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-processor
>   --disable-tools

For output of this see  [config.log](http://tny.cz/400fc11b)

My environment has the following variables set ..

```
CPP=arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
AS=arm-linux-androideabi-as
AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar
CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld
CFLAGS=--sysroot=/home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
CPPFLAGS=--sysroot=/home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
CXXFLAGS=--sysroot=/home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
SYSROOT=/home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:.:/home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
NDK_ROOT=/home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d
NDK=/home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d
```

When I run `make -j4` I get the following errors..

> ```
> src/client/linux/crash_generation/crash_generation_client.cc:34:21:
> ```
>
> fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

There are more similar errors related to stl [(full output here)](http://tny.cz/8ae91634).  So my question is how do I get this to build with those included.  I don't work in linux much so please try to be explicit with any answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following flags and reran config and then the compile succeeded.

```
CPPFLAGS=--sysroot=/home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -I /home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport

LDFLAGS=-L /home/desktop/Development/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi

LIBS=-lstlport_static
```